# What is the average distance between two random points inside an $n$-dimensional ball?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, probability-theory

Here "random" means independently and uniformly distributed with respect to the Lebesgue measure (i.e. $n$-dimensional volume).

This question is from the homework of a friend, where $n=100$.

My efforts:

Let the points be $A$ and $B$, and $O$ be the center of the ball. Let $r_1=|OA|,r_2=|OB|,\theta=\angle AOB$. Then, the three random variables $r_1,r_2,\theta$ are independent. $|AB|=\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta}$.

$P(r_1\le x)=$ volume of a ball of radius $x$ / volume of a ball of radius $1$ $=x^n$, so the density function $p(x)$ of $r_1$ (and similarly, $r_2$) is $\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=nx^{n-1}$ ($0\le x\le 1$).

Let $q(x)$ be the density function of $\theta$, where $0\le\theta\le\pi$. $q(x)$ is constant when $n=2$, and $q(x)=c\sin(x)$ when $n=3$.

*I don't know how to find* $q(x)$ for the general case, but I *guess* that $q(x)=c\sin^{n-2}(x)$ for the constant $c$ that can make its integral equal to $1$.

And the answer is
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^\pi \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta}\cdot p(r_1)p(r_2)q(\theta) d\theta dr_2 dr_1.
$$

Is my method correct? And how to calculate $q(x)$? Thank you.

Comment: Your guess is right but you should write $q(x)=c_n \sin^{n-2}(x)$. See https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=ajms.2011.66.70

Answer (score 1):

As $n \to \infty$, the expected distance between two random points in the unit  ball tends to $\sqrt{2}$. The reason is that most points in the ball are very near the sphere, and two independent random points in the ball are likely to be almost orthogonal.

Comment: Very interesting answer. I think you are correct. However, I would like to see some rigorous mathematics that supports your claims.